# glUseProgram() GL_INVALID_OPERATION 1282 on Ubuntu Gnome 17.04 Intel HD4000

Tags: linux, opengl, intel, sdl-2, mesa

I'm trying to learn openGL 3.0 by following the example on https://open.gl/drawing (It just draws a coloured rectangle on the screen).

I am using SDL2.0.5 and glew 2.0.0 with VS2015 community and it works perfectly on my i5 skylake HD4000 laptop running Win7 pro x64. However when I compile the exact same source on Ubuntu Gnome 17.04 x64 on the same laptop (dual booting Win and Linux) with gcc and glew 2.0.0, I get a `GL_INVALID_OPERATION 1282` error at `glUseProgram(shaderProgram)`.

Compiler runs with no warnings:

```
g++ main.cpp -Wall -I/usr/include/SDL2 -lGL -lGLEW -lSDL2 -lSDL2_image -lSDL2_mixer -o game
```

There are no errors before this function, (I removed the error checking code for clarity).

Also the screen goes from normal desktop to a blank black screen, then repeats until I quit the app. The screen blanking does not happen if I comment out the `SDL_GL_SwapWindow(gameWindow)`, but the error is still there.

I have tried changing the context to 3.3 and shader versions to #version 330 core - same problem.

I also used the Intel Graphics Update Tool to get the latest drivers.

Some system info below:

```
       product: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-3340M CPU @ 2.70GHz
       vendor: Intel Corp.
       physical id: 1
       bus info: cpu@0
       size: 3199MHz
       capacity: 3400MHz
       width: 64 bits
       capabilities: fpu fpu_exception wp vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx rdtscp x86-64 constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc aperfmperf pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx smx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm epb tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid fsgsbase smep erms xsaveopt dtherm ida arat pln pts cpufreq


 description: VGA compatible controller
       product: 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 09
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:29 memory:f6400000-f67fffff memory:e0000000-efffffff ioport:f000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff

OpenGL vendor string: Intel Open Source Technology Center
OpenGL renderer string: Mesa DRI Intel(R) Ivybridge Mobile 
OpenGL core profile version string: 3.3 (Core Profile) Mesa 17.0.3
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 3.30
OpenGL core profile context flags: (none)
OpenGL core profile profile mask: core profile
OpenGL core profile extensions:
OpenGL version string: 3.0 Mesa 17.0.3
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.30
OpenGL context flags: (none)
OpenGL extensions:
OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 3.0 Mesa 17.0.3
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 3.00
OpenGL ES profile extensions:
```

Source code:

```
#define GLEW_STATIC
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <SDL.h>
#include <SDL_opengl.h>
#include <iostream>

// SDL2 global pointers
SDL_Window* gameWindow = NULL;
SDL_GLContext context = NULL;
SDL_Surface* screenSurface = NULL;
SDL_Renderer* gameRenderer = NULL;

// Shader sources
const GLchar* vertexSource = R"glsl(
#version 150 core
in vec2 position;
in vec3 color;
out vec3 Color;
void main()
{
Color = color;
gl_Position = vec4(position, 0.0, 1.0);
}
)glsl";
const GLchar* fragmentSource = R"glsl(
#version 150 core
in vec3 Color;
out vec4 outColor;
void main()
{
outColor = vec4(Color, 1.0);
}
)glsl";

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_MASK, SDL_GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_CORE);
SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MAJOR_VERSION, 3);
SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MINOR_VERSION, 2);
SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_STENCIL_SIZE, 8);

if(SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING) != 0)
{
printf("SDL_Init failed! Error: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
return -1;
}
else printf("SDL_Init OK.\n");

gameWindow = SDL_CreateWindow("OpenGL", 100, 100, 400, 300, SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL);
if (gameWindow == NULL)
{
printf("SDL_CreateWindow failed! Error: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
SDL_Delay(1000);
SDL_Quit();
return -1;
}
else printf("SDL_CreateWindow OK.\n");


context = SDL_GL_CreateContext(gameWindow);
if(context == NULL)
{
printf("SDL_CreateWindow failed! Error: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
SDL_Delay(1000);
SDL_DestroyWindow(gameWindow);
SDL_Quit();
return -1;
}   
else printf("SDL_GL_CreateContext OK.\n");

glewExperimental=GL_TRUE;
GLenum glew_init_error = glewInit(); 

if (GLEW_OK != glew_init_error)
{  
fprintf(stderr, "glewInit failed! Error: %s\n", glewGetErrorString(glew_init_error));
SDL_Delay(1000);              
SDL_GL_DeleteContext(context);
SDL_DestroyWindow(gameWindow);
SDL_Quit();
return -1;
}   
else fprintf(stdout, "glewInit OK. Version: %s\n", glewGetString(GLEW_VERSION));

// Create Vertex Array Object
GLuint vao;
glGenVertexArrays(1, &vao);
glBindVertexArray(vao);

// Create a Vertex Buffer Object and copy the vertex data to it
GLuint vbo;
glGenBuffers(1, &vbo);

GLfloat vertices[] = {
-0.5f,  0.5f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, // Top-left
0.5f,  0.5f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, // Top-right
0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, // Bottom-right
-0.5f, -0.5f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f  // Bottom-left
};

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

// Create an element array
GLuint ebo;
glGenBuffers(1, &ebo);

GLuint elements[] = {
0, 1, 2,
2, 3, 0
};    

glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, ebo);
glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(elements), elements, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

// Create and compile the vertex shader
GLuint vertexShader = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
glShaderSource(vertexShader, 1, &vertexSource, NULL);
glCompileShader(vertexShader);

// Create and compile the fragment shader
GLuint fragmentShader = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
glShaderSource(fragmentShader, 1, &fragmentSource, NULL);
glCompileShader(fragmentShader);

// Link the vertex and fragment shader into a shader program
GLuint shaderProgram = glCreateProgram();
glAttachShader(shaderProgram, vertexShader);
glAttachShader(shaderProgram, fragmentShader);
glBindFragDataLocation(shaderProgram, 0, "outColor");
glLinkProgram(shaderProgram);

// ************** THE NEXT FUNCTION CALL FAILS WITH GL_INVALID_OPERATION  *********************************
glUseProgram(shaderProgram);  

// Specify the layout of the vertex data
GLint posAttrib = glGetAttribLocation(shaderProgram, "position");
glEnableVertexAttribArray(posAttrib);
glVertexAttribPointer(posAttrib, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 5 * sizeof(GLfloat), 0);

GLint colAttrib = glGetAttribLocation(shaderProgram, "color");
glEnableVertexAttribArray(colAttrib);
glVertexAttribPointer(colAttrib, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 5 * sizeof(GLfloat), (void*)(2 * sizeof(GLfloat)));

SDL_Event windowEvent;
while (true)
{
    if (SDL_PollEvent(&windowEvent))
{
    if (windowEvent.type == SDL_QUIT) break;
    if (windowEvent.type == SDL_KEYUP && windowEvent.key.keysym.sym == SDLK_ESCAPE) break;
}

// Clear the screen to black
glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

// Draw a rectangle from the 2 triangles using 6 indices
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);

SDL_GL_SwapWindow(gameWindow);
}

glDeleteProgram(shaderProgram);
glDeleteShader(fragmentShader);
glDeleteShader(vertexShader);
glDeleteBuffers(1, &ebo);
glDeleteBuffers(1, &vbo);
glDeleteVertexArrays(1, &vao);

SDL_GL_DeleteContext(context);
SDL_Delay(1000);
SDL_Quit();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Check whether the shaders compiled and linked successfully with `glGetShaderiv/InfoLog` and `glGetProgramiv/InfoLog`

Comment: `glBindFragDataLocation` is only present as of OpenGL 3.3.

Comment: As below, the glBindFragDataLocation() is in the program when it compiles and runs successfully in visual studio 2017, and the major/minor versions are also set to 3.2. So I don't know why it should only be available in 3.3? If that's right it's strange that it appears in this popular OpenGL tutorial at http://open.gl. I didn't know about glGetShaderiv/InfoLog & glGetProgramiv/InfoLog, so I'll gather the info from these and report back. Thanks! ;)

Comment: The use of prefix `R` in a string literal, as you do for shaders code, is new in C++11. If your GCC version is less than 6.1 then you need `-std=c++11` in your compiling command.

Comment: @Ripi2: My gcc version is gcc (Ubuntu 6.3.0-12ubuntu2) 6.3.0 20170406
. I added -std=c++11 anyway, still the same :( Thanks for the tip though! ;)

Comment: @BrettHale: When you say that the glBindFragDataLocation is only present as of OpenGL 3.3, but it states in this link that it is available in 3.0 & 3.2, (I'm using 3.2)   http://io7m.com/documents/fso-tta/ . I'm really new to this so I need to read up, but is this correct?

Answer (score 0):

**Check whether the shaders compiled and linked successfully with glGetShaderiv/InfoLog and glGetProgramiv/InfoLog** – pleluron

Thanks to Pleluron I added shader and linker error log code and found that, on my core i5 HD4000 Linux, the GPU driver did not support the 1.5 (#version 150) shader version I was using. When I changed the vertex & fragment shader versions to 1.3 (#version 130) and the major/minor SDL context attributes to 3.0 it cured the problem. (Although I did have to modify the shader code for GL3.0/GLSL1.3).

What confuses me is that glxinfo reports OpenGL3.3 and GLSL 3.3 below so I expected to be able to use precisely that...

```
OpenGL vendor string: Intel Open Source Technology Center
OpenGL renderer string: Mesa DRI Intel(R) Ivybridge Mobile 
OpenGL core profile version string: 3.3 (Core Profile) Mesa 17.0.3
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 3.30
OpenGL core profile context flags: (none)
OpenGL core profile profile mask: core profile
OpenGL core profile extensions:
```

... but also reports OpenGL 3.0 & GLSL 1.30 below, which seems to be the one being used when the context is created through SDL despite being asked for a higer version?

```
OpenGL version string: 3.0 Mesa 17.0.3
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.30
OpenGL context flags: (none)
```

I will dig into this and update this answer.

Comment: You set attributes before `SDL_Init`. I think init is free to reset them (and quick test confirms this, it resets at least on some platforms - but i'm not on linux currently).

Comment: @keltar : Thanks for the tip! I assumed that SDL needed the major/minor attributes to be set before SDL_Init for it to initialise properly. I'll modify my code to Init first, then set attribs, and see if that allows an OpenGL 3.3 / GLSL 3.3 context to be created. ;)

Comment: Yeah it should be after init but before window/context creation (probably just context; not sure). Please let me know of your results, as well as queried GL/GLSL version if problem will persist.

Comment: @keltar : Spot on! I'm now setting the GL attribs after SDL_Init and everything is working as it should.

Comment: Info from my debugging text and glGetIntegerv(Maj/Minor), glGetString(GL_SHADING_LANGUAGE_VERSION / GL_VENDOR / GL_RENDERER)..... 
        SDL_Init OK.
 SDL_CreateWindow OK.
 SDL_GL_CreateContext OK.
 glewInit OK. Version: 2.0.0
 GL major ver: 3
 GL minor ver: 3
 GLSL ver: 3.30
 vendor string: Intel Open Source Technology Center
 vendor string: Mesa DRI Intel(R) Ivybridge Mobile